# Terraform Aws S3 - deny all users except for a specific user

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-s3

I have a bucket which I need to restrict to a specific user, I have written the following script but it still seems to allow all users to operate on the bucket.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "vulnerability-scans" {
  bucket = "vulnerability-scans"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "vulnerability-scans" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.vulnerability-scans.id
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.vulnerability-scans.json
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "vulnerability-scans" {
  statement {
    principals {
      type = "AWS"
      identifiers = [
        aws_iam_user.circleci.arn,
      ]
    }

    actions = [
      "s3:PutObject",
      "s3:GetObject",
      "s3:ListBucket",
    ]

    resources = [
      aws_s3_bucket.vulnerability-scans.arn,
      "${aws_s3_bucket.vulnerability-scans.arn}/*",
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, let's understand how roles and policies work on AWS. In order for an user to be able to access a bucket, we can allow it in 3 ways:

1. Allow it using an IAM policy attached to the role the user is assuming;
2. Allow it using a bucket policy;
3. The group of the user has the policy attached to it or there is a policy directly attached to the user which allows access to the bucket.

These are explicit `Allow` policies. The user will have access if there is at least on policy from above granting him/her access.

What is important is that an explicit `Deny` takes precedence of an explicit `Allow`. So, if we want to deny access to a specific user, we would want to create a bucket policy with an explicit `Deny`. In order to do this, [we can use `NotPrincipal`](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-restrict-amazon-s3-bucket-access-to-a-specific-iam-role/).

Bucket policy example:

```
{
    "Id": "bucketPolicy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotPrincipal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:user/alloweduser"
                ]
            },
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "Version": "2012-10-17"
}
```

Terraform code for this policy:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "vulnerability-scans" {
  statement {
    not_principals {
      type = "AWS"
      identifiers = [
        aws_iam_user.circleci.arn
      ]
    }

    effect = "Deny"

    actions = [
      "s3:*"
    ]

    resources = [
      aws_s3_bucket.vulnerability-scans.arn,
      "${aws_s3_bucket.vulnerability-scans.arn}/*",
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: restrict as in only allow for that user. not deny it.